# Getting an access token using OAuth, the response appears to be encoded

Tags: java, oauth

I'm pretty new to OAuth and am trying to refresh a token using a simple java client. Everything seems to go ok (or I think it does), the problem is I can't tell from the response if it's a good one. The http response code is 200, but when trying to parse the response for access_token, I get a null. Also difficult to troubleshoot is the "raw" response is garbled, or encoded in some way. I was thinking maybe it's byte but it doesn't seem to be. Here's the code:

```
    private static String getClientCredentials() {  
        String postParams = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1234567890";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\"access_token\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]+)\".*");
        String clientId = "myClientID123";
        String clientSecret = "myClientSecret123";
        String tokenUrl = "https://www.host.com/oauth2/tenant/token";
        String auth = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
        String authentication = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
        
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        String returnValue = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(tokenUrl);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authentication);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            
            OutputStream outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(postParams.getBytes());
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
                        
            System.out.println("Resp code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Resp message: " + connection.getResponseMessage());

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            StringWriter out = new StringWriter(connection.getContentLength() > 0 ? connection.getContentLength() : 2048);
            
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }
            String response = out.toString();
            
            Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(response);
            if (matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
                returnValue = matcher.group(1);
            }

            System.out.println("response: " + response);
            System.out.println("returnValue: " + returnValue);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Here's the console output, sorry, I had to screenshot it because the characters didn't paste right:

[Response Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1NoG.jpg)

Am I trying something that isn't allowed or is there a way to decode the response so I can run the pattern match to extract only the access_token? Or am I going about it all wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated in advance!